# com.apple.developer.healthkit.access warning

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings, healthkit

I've added and created everything assigned to HealthKit but xcode shows this warning:

> Code Signing Warning: Provisioning profile ".." for ".." contains
>   entitlements that aren't in the entitlements file:
>   com.apple.developer.healthkit.access. To use these entitlements, add
>   them to your entitlements file. Otherwise, remove unused entitlements
>   from your provisioning profile.

I have tried to add com.apple.developer.healthkit.access key as a boolean value, but xcode cannot resolve that entitlement key-value (generates build error).
Everything is working correctly in the app with healthkit, but I'm worrying about the final distribution & dev distribution too.

**Update**

Because I didn't understand what is this warning about and I **didn't want to add unnecessary lines** to the entitlements I **uploaded the new version of the app to the App Store.** 
There wasn't any message from apple and rejection, so it's **now ready for sale**. This can be a useful information for those who worries about the rejection.

Answer (score 6):

In xxx.entitlements, add a new key `com.apple.developer.healthkit.access`, type is `Array` , and then keep it empty. Then the warning will be resolved.

As for the reason, it is still unclear.

Thanks to [Xcode HealthKit com.apple.developer.healthkit.access entitlements warning just started appearing](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/107381).

Comment: Thx for your answer. I found this solution already, the only thing why I did not answered or closed this question is as you mentioned, the answer is unclear.